# How to ready the line by line vales from the Notepad using Batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Seeking for you help.

I have a notepad named logging.txt and data in that logging.txt (Shown belowfrom) as follows:

```
File_Path=C:\QAPT_Automation
Duration=30
Port =150
outputfile= abc.dmc
```

Where batch file and logging.txt file are in the same folder.

So i need a batch script where i need to read the value of the variable from the text file (File_Path, Duration, Port, Outputfile) and should send to another function where all these values are used. 
So as of now cam anyone help me with the code where i can print the values in the function name xyz?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards:
Ravi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logging.txt :

```
File_Path=C:\QAPT_Automation
Duration=30
Port=150
outputfile=abc.dmc
```

test.bat :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (logging.txt) do set %%a

echo %File_path%
echo %duration%
echo %port%
echo %outputfile%
```

Comment: +1 That is sexy batch scripting mate. However it doesn't seem to work for the first line: `CQAPT_Automation` is what it produced for me.